# How to create thumbnails with Graphicsmagic?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and I m trying to play around with GraphicsMagic. I have installed GraphicsMagic in my windows pc and also installed gm module with npm install. I am able to get fullsize image but not able to create thumbs with the following code. can anyone help me to go in correct direction?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var fs = require('fs');
var gm = require('gm');


app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));                             
    app.use(express.bodyParser());                          
    app.use(express.methodOverride());                      
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");


app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
        var imageName = req.files.image.name;
        if (!imageName) {
            console.log("There was an error");
            res.redirect("/");
            res.end();
        } else {
            var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName;
            var thumbPath = __dirname + "/uploads/thumbs/" + imageName;
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
                gm(newPath)
                    .resize(240, 240)
                    .noProfile()
                    .write(thumbPath, function (err) {
                        if (!err) console.log('done');
                        res.redirect("/uploads/thumbs/"+imageName);
                    });
            });


        }
    });
});

app.get('/uploads/thumbs/:file', function (req, res) {
    file = req.params.file;
    var img = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/uploads/thumbs/" + file);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');

});


app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kind of a style tip: In the first `if` branch, replace `res.end()` with `return res.end()` and consider putting a 500 code in it. By using the `return`, you can lose the `else` and reduce the indentation of the logic underneath accordingly. Being callback based, indentation is the enemy. The solution is to name functions, and return early and often. Any time you see an else, try to avoid it with a return.

Comment: What is your errror? I guess its the same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453576/how-to-generate-thumbnail-image-from-gif-of-the-samesize-in-nodejs

Comment: @ptgamr : There is no error. It should generate an image thumb but it doesn't work.